# BindToMoniker Gets Two Windows then Windows(wb.Name).Visible Fails

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I'm trying to get an Excel file using BindToMoniker. For this question I'm starting with the no running instance of Excel (no workbooks open). It opens one Excel instance with two Excel windows shown. The one is entitled Excel and the other is titled with my workbook name. Neither of them show any open workbook.

Using Windows 10 64 bit with Excel 2016.

```
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindToMoniker(PathName)

Dim xlApp As Object = wb.Parent
xlApp.Visible = True

'error here
xlApp.Windows(wb.Name).Visible = True
```

I should be able to unhide the window using `xlApp.Windows(wb.Name).Visible = True` instead I get a `COMException: Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))` Just to verify I click on either window and in the View tab click Unhide. It shows the exact wb.name. I click OK to unhide and it does so just fine with the second window disappearing. Yet if I try to do that in the code it throws an error. So why does my code throw an error and/or how can I fix it?

EDIT: 
This also throws an error "invalid index"

```
xlApp.Windows(1).Visible = True
```

EDIT 2:

This works

1. I break the code at `xlApp.Windows(1).Visible = True`
2. Click on the Excel window entitled with wb.name
3. Execute the line `xlApp.Windows(1).Visible = True`

My workbook is unhidden and all is well. But if I click on the other window entitled "Excel" then it doesn't find any windows and my workbook stays hidden. I don't understand why it's opening two windows. That seems to be a problem.

I tried restarting my computer; no change.

So why am I getting two windows and why can't it find the hidden workbook to unhide it? What's the solution?

Comment: It may be an Explorer setting about showing file extensions. Try using: `wb.Windows(1).Visible = True` instead.

Comment: Is it still hidden, or just not the active workbook?

Comment: @Rory It's still hidden. I see an Excel window entitled with the name of my workbook but there is no workbook visible; It's hidden.

Comment: That would suggest to me that the workbook is in fact unhidden but possibly off screen - otherwise the window should not have the name as its caption. And you shouldn't be able to unhide it manually through the UI any more?

Comment: @Rory Sorry wrong information about windows(1); see my edit.

Comment: @Rory I think the key might be that there are two Excel windows. How do I access the second one when the xlapp says there are no windows?

Comment: I'm baffled! Looks a lot like a bug to me. If you output the window index in your `For Each` loop that works, what do you get?

Comment: I assumed that when you said your `For Each` loop **worked**, it actually *did* something! Is the workbook open when you run this code?

Comment: @Rory Window count is zero and yet in the UI I see the same hidden workbook in either Excel window.

Comment: I mean is it already open before you run this code?

Comment: @Rory No the workbook is closed before the code runs. But I'm using BindToMoniker in case it's open later.